# 'value at "/0" is required'

Tags: web3js, transactions, error

```
const {Web3} = require("web3");
require("dotenv").config();

const sPrivateKey = process.env.SENDER_PRIVATE_KEY;
const sPublicKey = process.env.SENDER_PUBLIC_KEY;
const rPublicKey = process.env.RECEIVER_PUBLIC_KEY_KEY;

async function main() {
  const web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(process.env.SEPOLIA_API_KEY)
  );
  const signer = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(sPrivateKey);
  web3.eth.wallet.add(signer);
  const estimatedGas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
    from: sPublicKey,
    to: rPublicKey,
    value: web3.utils.toWei("0.01", "ether"),
  });
  const tx = {
    from: sPublicKey,
    to: rPublicKey,
    value: web3.utils.toWei("0.01", "ether"),
    gas: estimatedGas,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: web3.utils.toWei("3", "gwei"),
    maxFeePerGas: web3.utils.toWei("3", "gwei"),
  };
  const signedTx = web3.eth.signTransaction(tx, signer.privateKey);
  console.log(signedTx.rawTransaction);
  const receipt = web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
  console.log(receipt.blockNumber);
}
main().catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Comment: You did not write where exactly you are getting this error. I can assume that it is sPrivateKey. Is it right?

Comment: Fixed it thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Find the problem and fixed it.

The part I fixed: Instead of rawTransaction after you write signedTx and put dot it shows you raw but I saw in an example of people doing it they wrote rawTransaction so I did the same but didn't work instead of tried raw and worked.

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! Suggest you write down the problem and fix, so that it can help others?